# Bias that makes annotators accept a prediction rather then coming up with a different label

Tags: bias, annotation

Many annotation tools can speed up the classification of images (or other data) by providing a prediction of the correct label which the user can accept or correct.
However, humans have a tendency to leave things as they are ([Status Quo Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_quo_bias)) or just accept the provided default option ([Default Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_effect)).

What name is commonly used for this effect? Are there scientific papers to cite that report and elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

The general term used to describe this phenomenon is "anchoring"; I don't know if there is an annotation-specific term.

[Anchoring and Agreement in Syntactic Annotations](https://aclanthology.org/D16-1239/) can be a starting point to reviewing relevant research.